# Как обновить список Bundle ID в itunesconnect?

Tags: ios, xcode

Когда в itunesconnect выбираю нужный Bundle ID (ID Пакета), в перечне предоставленных нет нужного. Хотя в провижн портале всё нормально.

Как обновить этот список, чтоб выбрать нужный?

Comment: Некоторое утверждают, что проблема решилась при использовании другого браузера. Кто то говорит, что надо залогиниться агентом, чтобы все обновилось.

Comment: Что за агент? пришлось менять новый Бандл, добавил к надписи Release 01 - появился)))